# C++14-ish code for creating q-grams of a string

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, c++14

I want to return an iterable collection of all *q-grams* of a provided string. This means all sub-words of length `Q`. Let `Q` be 3 for example:

`normalized` as an already whitespace-stripped and upcased word or string. `PREFIX3` and `SUFFIX3` are constant strings `^^` and`$$` that are put surrounding the string before splitting. That is a common trick to get more q-words.

For the word `INDEX` the resulting q-grams are therefore:

```
^^I  ^IN  IND  NDE  DEX  EX$  X$$
```

My version uses several C++14 constructs. This is intended, because the code is part of a lesson for teaching about C++14.

Is there anything I could do better, especially with respect to C++14-ish code?

```
vector<string> qwordify(const string& normalized) const
{
    auto word = PREFIX3 + normalized + SUFFIX3; 
    vector<string> result {};
    auto left = word.cbegin();
    auto right = word.cbegin() + Q; // valid, because |"^^"|+|"$$"| => 3.
    for( ; right <= word.end(); ++left, ++right) {
        result.emplace_back(left, right);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here are the things I considered especially:

- Despite of returning a value, `result` is not copied, because of RVO.
- Lots of `auto`, which I like.
- Use of `cbegin()` and  `cend()`, because I declared `auto word` and not `const auto word`. I could have done, but for this demonstration I liked to show the `c`-variants.
- Use of `emplace_back`, which really saves a copy here, correct?

I feel like some places could be improved, maybe. The iterators maybe? Getting rid of the loop in favor of an algorithm? Maybe even not returning a full `vector` at all, but only an iterable proxy-object, but that would too long a shot for this small example, I think.

Comment: Are you sure this compiles: free functions can't have the `const` modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things I like:

1. (Mostly) a pretty neatly packaged, self-contained component.
2. Written primarily to emphasize simplicity

   - and let the compiler deal with making it fast

Things I don't like so well:

1. `Q`, `PREFIX3`, and `SUFFIX3` are apparently globals (or maybe class variables?) so I can't see what they really are.
2. Subtle interaction: `PREFIX3` and `SUFFIX3` both (seem to) implicitly assume that `Q = 3`.
3. `qword` has a well-known meaning in Intel assembly language. Unless you're *sure* this will only be used by an audience that immediately knows what you intend, another name might be better.
4. Written non-generically, for no particularly good reason.
5. It almost seems like `qwordify` is really two separate things shoved together: a generic "generate all the results in a sliding window", and a specialized "generate all the qwords from a string".
6. If you can use the new `string_view`, it would be a good choice here.

Ignoring point 6 (since it's not really C++14), we could end up with code on this order:

```
// the generic algorithm:
template <class InIt, class OutIt, class size_type>
void window(InIt b, InIt e, OutIt d, size_type len) {
    for (auto s = std::next(b, len); s != e; ++s, ++b, ++d)
        *d = { b, s };
}

// The piece specifically for q-grams
std::vector<std::string> generate_qgram(std::string const &in, size_t q) {
    std::string input = std::string(q-1, '^') + in + std::string(q, '$');

    std::vector<std::string> words;

    window(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(words), q);
    return words;
}

// and a little demo code:
int main() {
    auto ret = generate_qgram("INDEX", 3);

    std::copy(ret.begin(), ret.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: `PREFIX3` etc `static const string` in this file, yes. Yes, they assume Q=3. I was thinking of to generate them, but that is hard with string as constexpr, I thought. So I tried with `static_asserion` on `PREFIX3.length() == Q-1`, but of course, could not (not `constexpr`). I didn't think if using the c'tor `string(char,size_t)`, thank you. Oops, good point about "qword", I will rename it to `qgram` and `qgramify`. Also good point about non-genericness. I didn't think of it, but still, I probably leave it because it is teaching code. I like your more separate version using `window`. Very good.